# WebView in React-Native and popups

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I am struggling with this issue for a while right now. I have an in-app browser, where I direct user to some webpage. In this webpage, there are popups, that are not working on in the WebView - they are not opening. I was trying to intercept them with `onNavigationStateChange` prop, and tried to navigate user to his native browser, but I've failed to do so - the popups never trigger any callbacks in the `onNavigationStateChange`. I was testing this using this [webpage](http://www.popuptest.com/). My question boils down to:

- Is is possible to intercept popups in the WebView, and if not - what approach can I take to make the popups available in the WebView or to somehow redirect user to his native browser, whenever the popup happens?

Comment: Hello, this is a fairly old question, did you manage to solve it? I'm facing this problem as well